# File loading difficulties in clisp

Tags: load, lisp, common-lisp, clisp

So I am trying to learn Lisp, and I downloaded GNU CLISP 2.49 on my Windows 10 PC. I wrote some code in a file already, and I want to load it from the CLISP terminal with the `(load "example.lisp")` command.

Where should I put the file to be able to load it like this in clisp?

I have the clisp installed in `C:\clisp-2.49`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should start with the docs for the [`load`](http://clisp.org/impnotes/loadfile.html) function, and the bottom of the page will give you the answer:

> Variable `CUSTOM:*LOAD-PATHS*`. The variable `CUSTOM:*LOAD-PATHS*` contains a list of directories where the files are looked for - in addition to the specified or current directory - by LOAD, REQUIRE, COMPILE-FILE and LOAD-LOGICAL-PATHNAME-TRANSLATIONS.

So, you should examine the variable `custom:*load-paths*` and add your directory there:

```
(pushnew #p"c:/home/lisp/" custom:*load-paths* :test #'equalp)
```

or you can run `clisp` in the directory where your sources are located.

PS. You now owe me [1 zorkmid](http://clisp.org/impnotes/faq.html#faq-fine). :-)

Comment: Hey Sam, might this user be using `clisp-2.49-win32-mingw-ming-big.exe` from Sourceforge? That reminds me, take a look a this: http://www.kylheku.com/cygnal/   Friends don't let friends use MingGW. :)

Answer (score 4):

In addition to `sds`'s excellent answer, here is a Windows perspective.

In a command-line environment on Windows or Unix, you wouldn't run into this issue, because it would be clear that you are are in certain "current working directory":

```
C:\Users\me\lisp_project> clisp -q
[1]> (load "example.lisp")
```

That is, loading a file using a relative path will be relative to this directory. It's clear in the above scenario that if the file `C:\Users\me\lisp_project\example.lisp`, that is what is loaded (unless someone has reconfigured `custom:*load-paths*` not to look in the current working directory).

When you start a process using the Windows Explorer GUI, it still has a current working directory. If you start a process by launching an `.exe` file, its working directory is the directory where that `.exe` is located.

If you launch an executable through a shortcut, however, the current working directory is determined by a property of the shortcut. You can edit this: right click on the shortcut and change the "Start in" directory to whatever you want.

In other words, you can make a shortcut to `clisp.exe`, place it into whatever folder you are working in, and have it "start in" that folder.

This approach should work for any language interpreter, including those which lack the sophistication of CLISP's `custom:*load-paths*`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load a file from your Desktop directory you can do:

```
(load "../../Users/User/Desktop/Dateiname.lisp")
```

Answer (score 0):

`clisp-2.49-win32-mingw-ming-big.exe` will not work if the current directory has spaces in it. Make sure that your directory does not have any spaces in it.